# How to selectively store user input in hash map using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, hash, ejs

I have an algorithm that takes as parameters a JSON file like so:

```
{"quiz": {                
  "algorithm_id_1": "4",
  "algorithm_id_2": "2",
  "algorithm_id_3": "3", 
   // ...
```

`algorithm_id` is an id of an input field, and the number that follows is the user's chosen value for that input field (most of which are sliders).

My question is as follows:

- How do I prevent overlap in the case that an input has the same id as another input? (e.g. `"algorithm_id_1": "2", "3"` rather than `"algorithm_id_1": "2", ... "algorithm_id_1: "3"`?

I'm currently getting each input field's id with its corresponding value, but each response is being stored as its own object.

```js
const allInputs = $(":input");

// retrieve
for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
  allInputs[i].value = localStorage.getItem(i);
}

// populate
jQuery(":input").change(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem(i, allInputs[i].value);

    // console.log($(":input").get(i).id);
    var map = {};
    var vals = allInputs[i].value;
    var keys = allInputs.get(i).id;
    map[keys] = vals;
    console.log(keys)
  }
});
```

Context: I'm sure there are easier ways to do this, but I'm limited to our current stack (Node.js and EJS) and do not have much say over what we're using. The purpose of this function is to gather responses from the user and then feed them into a recommendation algorithm. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your data structure, make the values of the keys arrays like so:

```
{
 quiz: {
   algorithm_id_1: [2,3],
   algorithm_id_1: [1,6],
   ...
 }
}
```

to do this you would need to modify how youre updating your data structure.

Basically, you'd need to check if the object already has a key of that name "algorithm_id_1", if it doesn't then add it and set its value to an array with the value the user entered. If it does exist already then push the newly entered value to the existing array.

In your example you're re-creating the map each time theres a change, it's not ideal but I won't address that here.

```
jQuery(":input").change(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    // localStorage.setItem(i, allInputs[i].value);

    // this is the part your question seems to be concerned with
    var map = {};
    var key = allInputs.get(i).id
    var val = allInputs[i].value;

    // if the key already exists in the map
    if(map[key]){
        map[key].push(val)
    } else { // otherwise add it and set its value to an array of 1 entry
        map[key] = [val]
    }

    // this should now be an object of key values where the values are arrays
    console.log(keys)
  }
});
```

I wasn't actually able to test the example with your jquery code, however I believe it should work.